# QtCreator doesn't show messages in application output

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I'm writing console application in QtC, and it has a lot of "cout << " outputs
also some of project configurations are unit tests (Catch uTest framework)
and nothing of this has shown in Application output window.
On Projects tab - Run in Console has been switched off. 
and I don't plan to use `qDebug()` because this project doesn't use Qt library

How can this be fixed?

Comment: for console apps Qt Creator opens up a console and runs your program there, is the output not in this console?

Comment: I've turned off console window in run settings, I'd prefer to see the output in application output window